# Symfony 3.4 : Filter/validate GET parameters

Tags: php, symfony, filtering, http-get, symfony-3.4

I would like to filter the data sent by a GET request in a symfony controller.

With the given data as an array by $request->query->all() for exemple, I want to filter the keys to only keep the one I need AND with the good type.

Ultimately, I want to pass the valid data as default data to a form builder createFormBuilder($my_valid_data) but it has to be correct since passing the wrong type (ie 2 dimensions array instead of array causes a crash).

Does Symfony provide such a feature ?

Thank you.

*Note : filter_var_array + array_filter isn't good enough since it will allow multidimensional when I need a single dimension one.*

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is wrong, but you don't give much info.
If the data is valid you probably don't need to pass that to a form (that what forms are for). You want to pass the original request to an actual form, and just get the values you want and discard the rest.

You can do this basically by creating a form that accepts the values you want and use [allow_extra_fields](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#allow-extra-fields) so you can discard the rest. That way you can just implement validation for the fields you are after.

EDIT: If you want to set some values for the form based on the request to the page, you can use [events](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) or even use `$form->setData()` before calling `createView` and passing the form to the template.

Comment: Probably I explained wrong then, My form is submitted as a POST, but i want to use GET parameters to fill it with default values. But maybe I got a wrong approach. So is there any good way to do it ? (not to mention, i don't use the same name of field name between POST and GET since FormBuilder will "prefix" them with form[])

Comment: You want to pass parameters to the url, so when you load the form, you have default values predefined on the form?

Comment: yes, like http://www.mywebsite.com/page?smth=4 will set the default value of smth to 4 in the form (form[smth]).

Comment: again, you should post your code so all this is easier to understand from the beginning. See my edited answer.